# If isConnected returns true, why does Exeption say that it isn't connected?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, kotlin

I am writing an android app that is supposed to send a file over Bluetooth. for now i am just trying to send text. The sending device appears to send correctly and the receiving device is receiving a connection from the other device. The receiver is able to get a socket from the listening server socket and an input stream from that. My problem is that it is not able to read from the input stream. The part that really perplexes me is that the Exception that i get indicates that the related socket is closed, however Socket.isConnected() returns true both before attempting to read, and after the Exception occurs. How can this be possible? How can this code:

```
class ReceiveThread(val socket: BluetoothSocket):Thread() {

var count:Int = 0
var bytes:Int = 0
val buffer:ByteArray = ByteArray(1024)
val byteList = mutableListOf<Byte>()
val inStream:InputStream

init {
    inStream = socket.inputStream
}

override fun run() {
    BluetoothService.log("Begin ${BTS_Constants.THREAD_RECEIVE}")
    BluetoothService.log("preparing to read data (socket connected): ${socket.isConnected}")
    name = BTS_Constants.THREAD_RECEIVE

    try {
        bytes = inStream.read(buffer)
    }catch (e:Exception){
        BluetoothService.log("error reading from stream (socket connected):${socket.isConnected}", e)
        BluetoothService.state = BTS_Constants.STATE_NONE
    }

    if (byteList.size>0) BluetoothService.log("data read: ${byteList.get(0) as Char}") else BluetoothService.log("failed to get")
}

fun cancel() = inStream.close()
}
```

result in this log message:

```
11-28 23:23:33.958 25325-25534/com.example.zemcd.fileblue D/BluetoothService: Begin RECEIVE
11-28 23:23:33.958 25325-25534/com.example.zemcd.fileblue D/BluetoothService: preparing to read data (socket connected): true
11-28 23:23:34.035 25325-25534/com.example.zemcd.fileblue E/BluetoothService: error reading from stream (socket connected): true

java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1

at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:588)

at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)

at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)

at com.example.zemcd.fileblue.ReceiveThread.run(BluetoothService.kt:263)
11-28 23:23:34.035 25325-25534/com.example.zemcd.fileblue D/BluetoothService: failed to get
```

If the socket is closed why is this returning true? How can i track down where my socket is closing? Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isConnected()` tells you about the state of the `Socket`. If you have ever connected or accepted it, it returns true. Even after you close it. It doesn't magically become false when the peer disconnects.

The exception is telling you about the state of the *connection*.

Comment: is there any way for me to track the state of the connection? So that I can see when the connection is being closed? Something similar to isConnected maybe but for the connection status? Or any other way to find out where the connection is being closed?

Comment: You've already found it. An exception is thrown when you do I/O. Any `IOException` other than `SocketTimeoutException` is fatal to the connection.

Comment: so the connection is closing right there when that exception is thrown? But isn't the Exception occuring because the connection is closed?

Comment: Please explain this to me. It would be very helpful.

Comment: If you're doing a send, the connection has already closed and been detected by the network, and it is reported to you next time you send. If you were blocking in a receive, the connection has just been dropped.

Comment: finally able to solve this thanks to your answer and some more research. combining my SendThread and ReceiveThread into one ConnectedThread with a continuous accept loop and Synchronized write function seemed to stop the connection being closed and still allow writing to the OutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
I've used this code to solve this problem

```
socket.socket.IsConnected
```

The first `socket` is a variable socket to connect to server.

The second `socket` is your server and you can get anything you want

And `IsConnected` will inform you if you have connection with server or not